# При попытке установить laravel/installer возникают ошибки

Tags: php, laravel, composer

```
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:56
Changed current directory to /home/nessie27/.config/composer
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:879
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:884
Using version ^5.2 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/installer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 28 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Normalizer" not found in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/String/AbstractUnicodeString.php:31
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php(84): [constant expression]()
#1 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(520): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Helper::length()
#2 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(580): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar::Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\{closure}()
#3 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\{closure}()
#4 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(593): preg_replace_callback()
#5 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(416): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->buildLine()
#6 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(325): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->display()
#7 /usr/share/php/Composer/Util/Loop.php(89): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->start()
#8 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php(497): Composer\Util\Loop->wait()
#9 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php(362): Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->waitOnPromises()
#10 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php(282): Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->downloadAndExecuteBatch()
#11 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(754): Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->execute()
#12 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(583): Composer\Installer->doInstall()
#13 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(279): Composer\Installer->doUpdate()
#14 /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php(430): Composer\Installer->run()
#15 /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php(285): Composer\Command\RequireCommand->doUpdate()
#16 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(298): Composer\Command\RequireCommand->execute()
#17 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(1015): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#18 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(299): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#19 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(336): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#20 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(171): Composer\Console\Application->doRun()
#21 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(131): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#22 /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/GlobalCommand.php(119): Composer\Console\Application->run()
#23 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(1015): Composer\Command\GlobalCommand->run()
#24 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(299): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#25 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(336): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#26 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(171): Composer\Console\Application->doRun()
#27 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(131): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#28 /usr/bin/composer(84): Composer\Console\Application->run()
#29 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/String/AbstractUnicodeString.php on line 31

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Normalizer" not found in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/String/AbstractUnicodeString.php:31
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php(84): [constant expression]()
#1 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(520): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Helper::length()
#2 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(580): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar::Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\{closure}()
#3 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\{closure}()
#4 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(593): preg_replace_callback()
#5 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(416): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->buildLine()
#6 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(325): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->display()
#7 /usr/share/php/Composer/Util/Loop.php(89): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->start()
#8 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php(497): Composer\Util\Loop->wait()
#9 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php(362): Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->waitOnPromises()
#10 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php(282): Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->downloadAndExecuteBatch()
#11 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(754): Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->execute()
#12 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(583): Composer\Installer->doInstall()
#13 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(279): Composer\Installer->doUpdate()
#14 /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php(430): Composer\Installer->run()
#15 /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php(285): Composer\Command\RequireCommand->doUpdate()
#16 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(298): Composer\Command\RequireCommand->execute()
#17 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(1015): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#18 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(299): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#19 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(336): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#20 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(171): Composer\Console\Application->doRun()
#21 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(131): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#22 /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/GlobalCommand.php(119): Composer\Console\Application->run()
#23 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(1015): Composer\Command\GlobalCommand->run()
#24 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(299): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#25 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(336): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#26 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(171): Composer\Console\Application->doRun()
#27 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(131): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#28 /usr/bin/composer(84): Composer\Console\Application->run()
#29 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/String/AbstractUnicodeString.php on line 31
```

Comment: ОС, команда какая ошибки даёт? Почему 5.2 версию ставите если актуальна 10+?